# Correctly shutting down the computer from an X session

Tags: x11, systemd, xinit

I run Debian 8.1 with the window manager Blackbox. The window manager is started from `~/.xinitrc`, and when the X session is done some cleanup commands are invoked:

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session blackbox
#cleanup
...
```

If I exit Blackbox by killing its process it works as expected. However, if I want to shut down the computer and run `systemctl poweroff`, the cleanup commands are never executed. How comes?

Comment: How about Exiting Blackbox normally then issuing poweroff from the terminal?

Comment: @eyoung100 I would like to setup the system so that a user don't have to use the command line (the shutdown command is invoked from a menu).

Comment: Then you need to see if blackbox can be used with a session manager like gdm or  xdm, and then add the session manager to the default runlevel.

Comment: @eyoung100 I would rather not use a display manager since I want to keep things as lightweight as possible.